# Health Check Failed [403] But API or App works fine.. How to Change to Unhealthy to Healthy

Tags: amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

API is working fine, but im still getting 403 or 301 errors during your Health Check, and I want to make it show as "Healthy" in Target Group - Load Balancer (LB).

Unhealthy to Healthy in Health Check in TG ( Target Group )

I Need to Change it in Target Group. Do we have any Solution in it..

Answer (score 1):

Go to Target Groups --> Scroll Down --> Click and Edit Health Checks --> Click Advanced health check settings --> Scroll Down Until You see the "Success Code" and Give the CODE 200,301,403 and Save..

Issue will be solved